# Если ли в Java механизм, обязывающий инициализовать поля класса в конструкторе?

Tags: java

Мой основной язык - TypeScript, и с опцией `strictPropertyInitialization: true` приведённый ниже код скомпилируется в JavaScript с ошибкой, если не проинициализировать `foo` в конструкторе.

```
class Example {

  // ошибка! Property 'foo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
  private foo: string;

  private constructor() {

  }

  private initializeFoo(foo: string): void {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  private getFooLength(newPart: string): number {
    return this.foo.length;
  }
}
```

Есть ли подобный механизм в Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, в `java` есть подобный механизм - это пометить поле как `final`. Тогда это поле можно будет объявить либо при описании, либо в конструкторе (или конструкторах, если у вас их несколько)

Код ниже скомпилируется успешно

```
class Example  {
    private final String name;

    public Example(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

А этот код уже не скомпилируется:

```
class Example  {
    private final String name;

    public Example() {

    }
}
```

Однако, у `final` есть ограничение - после того, как поле инициализировано, присваивать ему новое значение нельзя. В этом смысле, логика приведённого здесь кода неравносильна тому, что в вопросе (чтобы в TypeScript запретить присваивать новое значение, нужно пометить поле модификатором `readonly`).

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! С первого же предложения всё понял.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как же быть в случаях, если мы в будущем планируем переопределять `name`?

Comment: что значит переопределять поле класса? из потомка вы должны будете вызвать конструктор, передав туда нужный name. или я что-то не понял из вопроса

Comment: виноват, употребил некорректный термин. Я имел ввиду "присвоить новое значение".

Comment: смысл final поля в том, чтобы значение задать один раз и навсегда. больше его менять нельзя

Comment: Понял. Тогда, с Вашего решения, подредактирую Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Java создаёт дефолтный конструктор только, если вы явно не напишете хотя бы один свой конструктор. Вы можете написать что-то наподобие такого:

```
class Example { 

    private String foo;

    public Example(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

В таком случае Java не будет создавать дефолтный конструктор, а для создания экземпляра класса вам обязательно потребуется задать параметр foo

Comment: Тоже ценная идея! Благодарю Вас за ответ.